# Where to ask questions about Magento?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am a bit confused where the best place is to ask a question about Magento. There is a [Magento Stack Exchange site](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) for Magento questions. But, there are also questions about Magento on Stack Overflow

From a personal point of view questions about Magento on Stack Overflow get more views than on Magento.SE.

Wouldn't it be good to redirect people who want to ask something about Magento (have Magento in the tags list) to Magento.SE?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magneto

Answer (score 4):

If the question is Magento-related but *not* programming-related (see e.g. [How do you give estimates for Magento upgrade?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12736211/3001761)), then it is on-topic **only** on MagentoSE. If these questions are asked on SO, you should certainly add a comment/custom hold reason redirecting the OP to MagentoSE.

However, there are some questions that *are* programming-related, and could either sit in  [magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento) on SO **or** on MagentoSE. As you point out, the traffic for those questions is likely to be higher on SO, although maybe the Magento-specific experts are more available on MagentoSE.

In these cases, I would certainly make the user *aware* that MagentoSE exists, as they may have other questions that fit better there, but there's no reason to suggest they move it across *if the question is good and on-topic for SO* (or vice versa; questions on MagnetoSE that *would also* be on-topic on SO should stay where they are).

If it's just a bad question, that would be closed on either site in its current form, then close it where it is and encourage the user to read the Help Center advice on whichever site you think it would be most appropriate on - migrating bad questions helps nobody.

Comment: It's so hard not to write Magneto...

Answer (score 1):

Sites are often distinct, but they can overlap on occasion. That is not really a problem and there is no reason to direct users away from SO if their question is perfectly on-topic for the site.

In short, if you want an answer as to where to ask your Magento question; ask where it is on-topic. Check the help center to determine if your question is a good fit for either of the respective sites. And if it's on-topic on both sites, pick one.

Comment: In terms of "pick one", I'd offer the guidance of gauging potential response. Is it a question that is mostly PHP-related, but integrates with Magento? If so, then SO would be better because your pool of PHP developer will be larger there. However, if it's mostly related to Magento internals, you'd be far more likely to get a good answer at the Magento SE site.

Answer (score -4):

You can visit this **[Magento forum](http://forum.cmsideas.net/)** by Cmsideas, forum for all Magento beginners.

Comment: Question: _Wouldn't it be good to redirect people who want to ask something about Magento (have Magento in the tags list) to Magento.SE?_ Possible spam, does not answer the question